# Post a Message to Elastic Beanstalk Worker Environment via SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a docker application on elastic beanstalk with a web-server and worker environment.

The worker environment currently runs scheduled jobs via cron.
I'm trying to connect the server to the worker to achieve the following:

1. Client sends a request to the server (/trigger_job)
2. Server offloads the job to the worker by sending a JSON message to SQS queue (/perform_job)
3. Worker performs the job by reading the message from SQS

I haven't been able to find documentation on what the JSON message should look like. There are some HTTP headers mentioned [in the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html). But there's no mention of header to specify the desired endpoint in the worker environment.

```python
# server.py
from bottle import post, HTTPResponse


@post('/trigger_job')
def trigger_worker_job():
    # should send a JSON message to sqs to trigger the '/perform_job'
    # Need help with what the JSON message looks like
    return HTTPResponse(status=200, body={'Msg': 'Sent message'})
```

```python
# worker.py
from bottle import post, HTTPResponse


@post('/perform_job')
def perform_job():
    # job is performed in the worker environment

    return HTTPResponse(status=200, body={'Msg': 'Success'})
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Jeez stuck here as well. I'm wondering if they maybe wrap it in something like "body": etc.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can see how this from the python sample application where you can find on this [aws doc step 4: Deploy a New Application Version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.html#GettingStarted.Walkthrough.DeployApp).

You can configure SQS endpoint in beanstalk worker environment console. Configuration > Worker > Select a Worker Queue

```
# for example: 
environ['HTTP_X_AWS_SQSD_TASKNAME']
environ['HTTP_X_AWS_SQSD_SCHEDULED_AT']
logger.info("environ X-Aws-Sqsd-Queue %s" % environ['HTTP_X_AWS_SQSD_QUEUE'])

# regarding your message attribute. For example, the attribute name is Email, 
# you can extract it via environ['HTTP_X_AWS_SQSD_ATTR_EMAIL']). 
# Make sure that the attribute name is all capital.  
logger.info("environ X-Aws-Sqsd-Attr Email %s" % environ['HTTP_X_AWS_SQSD_ATTR_EMAIL'])
```

The message will contains the following info in the image. You can read more on [aws AWS Elastic Beanstalk Worker Environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html#using-features-managing-env-tiers-worker-settings)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found from some of my failed cron jobs in the dead letter queue, there were the following three attributes:

- beanstalk.sqsd.path
- beanstalk.sqsd.task_name
- beanstalk.sqsd.scheduled_time

which are similar to the attributes set on the cron job.

You can manually create a new message in the SQS queue for the worker environment and set those attributes to match the cron job you wish to execute, though that is tedious and I much prefer to do so by code.

I'm using the boto3 framework in python, though hopefully it is a similar process in other languages.

```
def send_elastic_beanstalk_message(name, path, message):
    client = boto3.client('sqs')
    return client.send_message(
        QueueUrl=url, 
        MessageAttributes={
            "beanstalk.sqsd.path": {
                "DataType": "String",
                "StringValue": path
            },
            "beanstalk.sqsd.task_name": {
                "DataType": "String",
                "StringValue": name
            },
            "beanstalk.sqsd.scheduled_time": {
                "DataType": "String",
                "StringValue": datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC')
            }
        }
    )
```

This will create a new message in the SQS queue that will be parsed by the worker daemon and trigger a cron job.

Unfortunately, a message body does not seem to be included when the message is parsed, so triggering the job is the only action I was able to solve.